# Memory management with CFTree

Tags: ios, multithreading, memory-management, tree, core-foundation

I need to represent data in tree datastructure in my iOS app.After doing a research, i found CFTree suits my case.But we need to explicitly handle memory management with CFTree.My tree should be thread safe,since multiple threads can add/delete/modify nodes in tree.So my question is

1)Is CFtree really helpful for maintaining hierarchical data in iOS?
2)How to handle memory management in a thread safe way?.
3)Is there any better way to maintain hierarchical data?.

There are limited tutorials for CFtree.Can anyone explain deeply about CFTree and its memory mangement?,if possible some code samples would help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CFTree` is low level C structure from `CoreFoundation`. Wouldn't it better and easier to write your own tree/node structure?